# Intellij not regconizing resources's sub-folder as class path.

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have a Java Spring web app built using Intellij. In my folder structure, I have a `Resources` folder, in that folder I have another folder call `Properties`, within that folder, there are 4 folders, one of them call `DEV` which contains a `.properties` file. How do I get Intellij to accept `DEV` as classpath? If I move `.properties` file to `Resources` folder then it works fine,  so it seem like Intellij took `Resources` folder as classpath, but not the subfolders.

```
Resources
--Properties
  --DEV
     app.properties
  --folder2
  --folder3
  --folder4
```

Comment: How are are reading the file in the location?  Can you show us your code?

Comment: Sure it *included* the subfolders as *part of* the classpath. Try `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/Properties/DEV/app.properties")`. Intellij will not *flatten* the content of the `Resources` folder, and it certainly shouldn't.